# cakephp change default url of view

Tags: php, url, cakephp

I have a controller which named `users_controller` and the views placed in `/users/` so this can be reached at `example.com/users/xxx`.
I'm wondering how could i change default url to `example.com/xxxx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to read up about CakePHP's Routing:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

It explains how to do just what you're asking and so much more.